# Find domain of function with quadratic numerator algebraically

Tags: functions, quadratics

I'm stuck on this problem:

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2 -4}{x}$$

I need to determine why this function's domain is **not**:  $$\{x|x \neq \pm 2\}$$ All of the examples that I've seen have the quadratic in the denominator, and then you just factor them out, and solve for ***x***. How do you find the domain of this function algebraically?

Comment: The only bad $x$ is $0$.

Comment: So then the domain would be $$\{x|x\neq\pm0\}$$ yes?

Comment: Well, saying $\pm 0$, though not wrong, seems unreasonable, since $-0=0$.

Comment: Fair enough too quick to copy/paste. When I graph the function out though on my ti-89 {x|x\±2} seems to look true. Why is that?

Comment: The function only goes bad at $x=0$. The function is $0$ at $x=\pm 2$, that's perfectly fine. If your graph seems to blow up at $\pm 2$, it can only be input error.

Comment: I don't know what you're seeing on your TI-89, but WolframAlpha shows something that's just fine at $x=\pm 2$. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E2-4%29%2Fx

Comment: What's with the integral sign?

Comment: Apologies for my ineptitude, but the x intercepts are at -2, 2 on your WolframAlpha. I don't get it!

Comment: $x$ intercepts are fine, it's when it goes off to infinity that it's not fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only value not allowed is one that will make the denominator equal to $0$, because you cannot divide by $0$. In this case, setting $x$ to $0$ will make the denominator equal to $0$. So, $x\neq 0$. Therefore the domain is:
$$\{x\mid x\neq 0\}$$

---

**Extra details:**

The graph of the function is:

[image: Foo]

Notice how there is a vertical asymptote at $x=0$. The graph starts approaching infinity at the left, reaches $x=0$ where it is not defined, and then "drops" all the way to negative infinity and starts increasing again.

---

**Why the domain is not $\{x\mid x\neq \pm 2\}$:**

Remember, the values not allowed come are ones that make the *denominator* equal $0$, not the numerator. It seems that you are trying to find the $x$-intercepts. To find the $x$-intercepts, one must make $f(x)=0$ . In this case, you would make the *numerator* equal to $0$. That means solving for $x$ in the equation $x^2-4=0$, which gives you $x=\pm 2$.